# How to convert my Android project to a maven project

Tags: android, performance, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have an Android project developed with Eclipse & pushed to github.

Now I want to convert my **Android project** to a **maven** project, how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Try to follow the [Getting Started Guide](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted) of the maven-android-plugin. In order to convert your already existing project you basically have to:

1) Create a `pom.xml`. For this you can use the maven archetype as described [here](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes):

```
mvn archetype:generate   
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart   
   -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes   
   -DarchetypeVersion=1.0   
   -DgroupId=your.company   
   -DartifactId=my-android-application
```

This will create the `pom.xml` and the directory structure mandated by maven.

2) Move your code into the respective folders under `src/main/java`.

3) Make sure you have the android sdk installed and in your path, the correct android platform version installed and referenced in your pom. Also make sure you have set all environment variables as required on the maven-android-plugin page

4) Issue `mvn clean install` on the command line and check if the build works

5) Plug in your Android device and issue `mvn android:deploy`. This should install the App on your mobile phone (you can verify the device's precence with `mvn android:devices`. If you want to execute the app in the emulator, start it first with `mvn android:emulator-start` and then deploy it.

6) Remove old files and folders that are no longer necessary.

7) In Eclipse, make sure you have maven support enabled and re-import your project. When Eclipse builds the project, it may complain about missing maven plugin support. Open Eclipse Marketplace and install the Android Configurator for m2e, then it should be ok.